# Invoking static methods containing Generic Parameters using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

While executing the following code i gets this error "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true."

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo MI = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("TestProc");
        MI.MakeGenericMethod(new [] {typeof(string)});
        MI.Invoke(null, new [] {"Hello"});
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public static void TestProc<T>(T prefix) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

The above code is just a scaled version of the actual problem i am facing. Please help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are calling `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` but throwing away the return value. The **return value** itself is the method you want to `Invoke` :

```
MethodInfo genericMethod = MI.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(string) });
genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { "Hello" });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I missed out the return value from MakeGenericMethod, instead i took the previous one which didn't contain the generic type information.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem with the code that you post is:

```
MI.MakeGenericMethod(new [] {typeof(string)});
```

Should be

```
MI = MI.MakeGenericMethod(new [] {typeof(string)});
```

You're not grabbing a reference to the 'baked' generic.